# minmax() with max-content not possible?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to do something like this:

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
```

But instead of having the grid items jump to `1fr` when they reach `< 200px` I'd like that to kick in depending on the `max-content` of those items. I tried this:

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(max-content, 1fr));
```

But that just make each item 100% wide each on their own row, and Chrome is telling me it's not valid syntax…  I might be missing something obvious

Any pointer in the right direction much appreciated!

Comment: it's invalid because max-content will depend on the content of each element and cannot be used to define the width of all the columns since each element is different

Comment: I was thinking it would just pick the widest of them since the grid element is aware of all the elements in relation to each others… Guess I was wrong  Thanks!